# Mathieu equation solution with non-periodic boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I need to solve the Mathieu equation:

$y''(x)+(a-2q \cos(2x)) y(x) = 0$

but with the unusal boundary condition:

$y(x+\pi) = e^{i \alpha}y(x) \quad , \quad \alpha \in R$

if $\alpha = 0$ than the solution are $se_n , ce_n$, but what about this case?

thanks

Comment: Out of curiousity, in what context are you interested in the Mathieu equation with twisted boundary conditions? (My own experience with it in physics is in the context of solving the problem of an electron on a periodic potential for generic quasimomentum.)

Comment: In my case its a Hamiltonian describing a josephson junction with an external lead (this is what gives the twisted boundary conditions). It's analogues to a quandum pendulum with a charge on the end, and a constant magnetic field.

Comment: Right. Let me do some quick googling to remind myself of the details.

Comment: Ok. What you want are Mathieu functions with noninteger order. Take a look at http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2 for reference.